# Application.OnKey not working in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running a macro using `Application.OnKey "%x", "myMacro"`. But now it's not working, could there be any reasons this is not working? 
Also if i wanted to change it and use `ALT + SHIFT + "x"` would it be `"%+x"` ? I've tried and it still haven't work. any ideas?

Comment: Don't use `OnKey` to do this. You should be able to call the sub directly from the code.

Comment: I need to use it. could it be that alt x cannot be changed for the hot key?

Comment: Why do you need to use it? I have yet to see a situation where it is necessary to trigger a macro using a keyboard shortcut within a typed macro.

Comment: @Kyle: Just because you personally don't see a reason for something doesn't make it invalid.  The functionality exists for a reason -- because some people have a need for it.

Comment: @orev Yes, that is true, but my question is still valid. It is commonplace for folks on SO to try to tease out what the OP is trying to accomplish as opposed to what method they are using to accomplish it. Often there are better methods to solve problems that the method the OP is using. I'm simply curious why the OP finds it necessary, so I know if I should spend my time trying to answer it, or offer a potentially better solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's obviously a bit late, but since it took me a lot of googling to finally find the answer, it might help make it more likely for others to run into the answer in the future.

I have no programming background, and all I wanted was to make `Ctrl+Shift+V` paste the formatting of a copied cell much like it does in Word. The following *should* have worked, but wouldn't:

```
Sub pfkey()
    Application.OnKey "^+v", "pformat"
End Sub

Sub pformat()
' Pastes the formatting of a copied selection

    Selection.PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Despite being syntactically correct, this will only work if you first "run" the module. What I did was:

1. Select the module containing the `pfkey()` subroutine
2. Press **F5**
3. Select **pfkey** again in the dialogue box
4. Click **run**

Bam -- working code.

[Where I found the answer:](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/602726-application-onkey-not-working.html) *"AFTER running the macro, the key combination would be assigned."*

Comment: This is great, but it doesn't persist after closing excel.  Is there a way to "run" the macro every time I open Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a cue from @Zoraal, I found that you can create an Auto_Open() sub that includes any/all of your application.onkey requirements.  This will "activate" them on starting excel so you don't need to manually run the module every time.

I use the personal workbook method [(discussed here)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566) to store all my macros.  I simply created a module called shortcuts and put in the following subroutine:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{yourshortcuthere}", "yoursub"
    Application.OnKey "{yourothershortcuthere}", "yourothersub"
End Sub
```

The reference macros can be contained in multiple other modules.